# SMTP client mail address replaced

Tags: c#, smtp, smtpclient

I have a problem when sending an email in C# using SMTP.

I have an SMTP host

```
mysmtphost.mydomain.com
```

while my email is

```
myname@mydomain.com
```

When I check the mail message object right before then call

```
smtpClient.Send(message)
```

it states from

```
myname@mydomain.com
```

However when the message is received by the user, the from address is

```
myname@mysmtphost.mydomain.com
```

I have tried on a different smtp server (smtp.mydomain.com) and everything works fine. Any clues?

Comment: Likely this is not a programming problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your outgoing SMTP server (mysmtphost.mydomain.com) is re-writing the headers on the message, replacing the sender's address myname@mydomain.com with myname@mysmtphost.mydomain.com.  This is not unusual - Gmail's outgoing smtp server (smtp.gmail.com) does this as well.